# TCanvasAttribute.MaxBitmapSize value in OnActivate event

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe6

I know this is a very specific case, so I would like to explain what the real problem is.

I have a FMX form that is sometimes used as a separate window and sometimes embedded in another form. When the form is activated, it will check if anything has changed and if so, it will reload some images. However I found out that if the form has `BorderStyle = None`, than at first activation `TCanvasAttribute.MaxBitmapSize` returns value `1024`, but every other is `8192`. Which is a problem for setting the dimensions from bitmap using `img1.Bitmap.LoadFromStream`.

When I tried to find out where this value came from, I got a constant `MaxAllowedBitmapSize`, so I don't even understand how it could be possibly changed. I'm not sure if this is a bug or some special behaviour, so I would appreciate any help.

Here is a simple test application that should work at least on XE6.

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  BorderStyle = None
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 480
  ClientWidth = 640
  FormFactor.Width = 320
  FormFactor.Height = 480
  FormFactor.Devices = [Desktop, iPhone, iPad]
  OnActivate = FormActivate
  DesignerMobile = False
  DesignerWidth = 0
  DesignerHeight = 0
  DesignerDeviceName = ''
  DesignerOrientation = 0
  DesignerOSVersion = ''
  object img1: TImage
    MultiResBitmap = <
      item
      end>
    Align = Client
    Height = 480.000000000000000000
    Width = 640.000000000000000000
  end
end
```

and form's `OnActivate` event

```
procedure TForm1.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
var
  lSize : Integer;
begin
  lSize := img1.Bitmap.CanvasClass.GetAttribute(TCanvasAttribute.MaxBitmapSize);
end
```

Comment: Is this on a particular platform? If so, which one?

Comment: Win32,I didn't try the others

Comment: I'm not sure that this has anything to do with your problem... but embedding a form in a form is not something I'd do in FireMonkey. I'd move the contents and logic in a frame and then embed the frame wherever I need it.